# Django, use context in serializer with many=True

Tags: django-rest-framework

I would like to set a context in a serializer while many=True but I don't know how to.

In my app I have groups of products, every product has a price. For every group I'm setting a context containing the highest and lowest price of the product of this group.
I request one group (/api/groups/id) or many (/api/groups/?quantity=X)

I have a working solution for requesting at a specific group. The context is calculated correctly and sent to the serializer.

Here is the code :

view :

```
    def get(cls, request, pk, format=None):
        """
        Return a specified ProductGroup.
        """

        try:
            product_group = ProductGroup.objects.get(pk=pk)
            serializer = ProductGroupSerializer(product_group, context=get_context(product_group))
# Here context is like : {'lowest_product_price': XX, 'highest_product_price': YY}
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            raise

        return Response(data={}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

serializer :

```
class ProductGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    lowest_product_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    highest_product_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_lowest_product_price(self, obj):
        return self.context.get('lowest_product_price', '')

    def get_highest_product_price(self, obj):
        return self.context.get('highest_product_price', '')

    class Meta:
        model = ProductGroup
        fields = ('id',
                  'name',
                  'lowest_product_price',
                  'highest_product_price',
                  'creation_date',)
```

I don't know how to handle the context when many groups are requested, I'm then using the many=True attribute while setting my serializer.

Here is the actual code for getting a pack of groups, this one should be changed :

```
def get(cls, request, format=None):
        """
        List the latest ProductGroups. Returns 'product_group_quantity' number of ProductGroup.
        """

        product_group_quantity = int(request.query_params.get('product_group_quantity', 1))
        product_group_list = ProductGroup.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:product_group_quantity]

        if product_group_list:
            serializer = ProductGroupSerializer(product_group_list, context=???????, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(data={}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**SOLUTION** thanks to Kimamisa

> Basically, you don't need to know if you are in a many or single case. The best approach would be to always pass a dict as a context, with obj id as a key

serializer :

```
class ProductGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lowest_product_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    highest_product_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_lowest_product_price(self, obj):
        context_data = self.context.get(obj.id, None)
        if context_data:
            lowest_product_price = context_data['lowest_product_price']
        else:
            lowest_product_price = ''
        return lowest_product_price
    def get_highest_product_price(self, obj):
        context_data = self.context.get(obj.id, None)
        if context_data:
            highest_product_price = context_data['highest_product_price']
        else:
            highest_product_price = ''
        return highest_product_price
    class Meta:
        model = ProductGroup
        fields = ('id',
                  'name',
                  'lowest_product_price',
                  'highest_product_price',
                  'creation_date')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you don't need to know if you are in a many or single case. The best approach would be to always pass a dict as a context, with obj id as a key